# shiny-server account not deploying web-page

Tags: shiny, shiny-server

I have signed up to the shiny-server website as I am using a Mac and find it difficult to install the software necessary to make a server difficult.

having signed in I then use the following code:

```
 rsconnect::setAccountInfo(name='tb-project-with-limma',
             token='6D6FF245028735CCD75C11E105605C98',
             secret=<insert_secret>)
 library(rsconnect)
 rsconnect::deployApp('path/to/your/app')
```

In the directory of interest, there is a script called "app.R" as instructed by the website. However, it seems to work up until the following error:

```
   "Uploading bundle for application: 92144...--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---

   DONE

   Deploying bundle: 410218 for application: 92144 ...

   Error: HTTP 409

   POST https://api.shinyapps.io/v1/applications/92144/deploy
```

Unable to dispatch task for application-92144: 1 tasks in progress"

A server page only appears on my browser if there's an error in the code to return the error eg. "Cannot install packages".

But when the code is error-free, no server page appears and only the following error is returned:

```
   "building: Fetching packages

   ################################ Begin Task Log ################################ 

   ################################# End Task Log ################################# 

   Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 179105393 error: Unhandled Exception: HTTP 599: Stream closed"
```

Any tips?

I should mention that downloading the shiny-server for my mac manually is awkward because for some reason my computer doesn't have the library "CGImage.h" and I get an error every time I try to follow the instructions of this link: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/wiki/Building-Shiny-Server-from-Source

Comment: It seems that you were deploying your code to `shinyapps.io`, but you also mentioned that you are building Shiny Server from source, why?

Comment: I am trying both options but I just wanted to explain why each one is not working- as long as i can get the deployment of the server to work it's fine